# Niṣedha padārthas (items prohibited from eating)

Tags: scripture, belief, food, vishwamitra

Can some one explain me about Niṣedha padārthas i.e., items prohibited from eating?

I have heard about few vegetables which were grown by Vishwamitra out of anger, therefore, they're not to be consumed. Does anyone know which scripture mentions these?

Comment: What is/are "neshidha padarthagalu?" Can you explain that word? Is that Sanskrit?

Comment: No this is kannada. I meant Contraband things (Like fruits and vegetables)

Comment: Oh so the sanskrit equivalent word would be Nishidya Padarthas(food items)

Comment: may be it must be

Comment: Nishiddha=Forbidden/prohibited...But Padartha does not necessarily mean food items..It can mean thing,ingredient,substance etc..in my state (West Bengal) consuming some vegetables are avoided in particular days/months and even on Tithis..But i don't know how Rishi Viswamitra is related to all of these..

Comment: Apparently Viswamitra created some vegetables in the Trisanku swarga. The nishiddha padArthAs were strictly adhered to during pitR karmAs up until a couple of generations ago. Onions are still avoided but green peppers (green chillies) are used these days when pepper corns (miriyam) are supposed to be used. In a nutshell, the banned substances are banned because they are Viswamitra sRiShTi.